# Expanding dataset with open and closed years to time series with dummy variable for open/closed across all years in dataset

Tags: time

I have a dateset of movie theaters that looks like this.

```
name <- c("cinema 1", "cinema 2")
open <- c("1933", "1934")
closed <- c("1935", "1935")
example_original <- data.frame(name, open, closed)
example_original
```

I'd like to convert it (preferably w/ tidyr) to look like this.

```
name2 <- c("cinema 1","cinema 1","cinema 1", "cinema 2", "cinema 2", "cinema 2")
year <- c("1933", "1934", "1935", "1933", "1934", "1935")
open_closed_dum <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1)
example_target <- data.frame(name2, year, open_closed_dum)
example_target
```

Answer (score 0):

1. *all years in dataset*: `years = with(example_original, min(open):max(closed))`

   ```
   [1] 1933 1934 1935
   ```
2. *Expanding dataset*: `merge(years, example_original)`

   ```
        x     name open closed
   1 1933 cinema 1 1933   1935
   2 1934 cinema 1 1933   1935
   3 1935 cinema 1 1933   1935
   4 1933 cinema 2 1934   1935
   5 1934 cinema 2 1934   1935
   6 1935 cinema 2 1934   1935
   ```
3. put together in desired form:

   ```
   years = with(example_original, min(open):max(closed))
   example_target = with(merge(years, example_original),
                         data.frame(name, year=x, open_closed_dum=(open<=x)*(x<=closed)))
   ```

   ```
         name year open_closed_dum
   1 cinema 1 1933               1
   2 cinema 1 1934               1
   3 cinema 1 1935               1
   4 cinema 2 1933               0
   5 cinema 2 1934               1
   6 cinema 2 1935               1
   ```